# What's the song that plays when Naruto and Sasuke fight with Rasengan and Chidori in episode 216?

Tags: naruto, music

In *Naruto Shippuden* episode 216, at around 7 minutes, there's a song when Sasuke and Naruto fight with Rasengan vs Chidori.

What's that song?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like Samidare (Track 28 of Shippuuden OST 2).

Note that parts of this track also sound vaguely similar to Ochibabune (OST 2 track 26), Yamagasumi (OST 2 track 22), and Utsusemi (OST 1 track 7), so it can be easy to confuse them.

Incidentally, Utsusemi was playing in the immediately preceding scene.